# Windows live contact API

Tags: windows, api

I am trying to use the windows live contact rest api,

for this i need a location id and delegation token, but i don't  know where do i get these.

if any one knows please let me know.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this site - https://manage.dev.live.com/

Unfortunately, the Windows Live Contact API is deprecated, that means the app id and delegation token is not available to you.

The new API can be found here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live/hh528486.

And you may want to take a look http://isdk.dev.live.com/, which provides you to exploring the API that you may want.

Comment: this site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287659.aspx quotes - "This topic describes functionality that will be obsolete. This functionality is provided only to support legacy applications. Live Connect incorporates features that provide equivalent functionality."